# How to play song in Android - phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, audio

A month ago I started working with phonegap, html5, css3 and jQtouch.
I am working on an application and I need to play sound in the application. I have a serious problem with this task.
First I've found out that I can play .mp3 files through phonegap using the new Media(...) function. I am not sure about .wav files, can I play those?
Second I've found that files must be less than 30 sec, is this so?
Third I can't find the right place for my sound files. My project structure is the following:

```
project
-- src
-- gen
-- assets
-- -- www
-- -- DANCE.mp3
-- -- jqtouch
-- -- -- (some folders and files)
-- -- phonegap.js
-- libs
-- res
```

I've tried placing the file in 'www' folder and creating a new one called 'audio'. None of this gave me what I wanted.
I am using this code for executing the song:

```
function playStream() {
    mp3file = new Media("DANCE.mp3",
            function() {
                alert("playAudio():Audio Success");
            },
                function(err) {
                    alert(err);
            }
            );
          mp3file.play();
}
```

I use Android 2.1 Simulator and I've tried 2.2 as well without success.
I hope I was clear enough.
I am looking forward to hearing from you.
Yours,
Mihail Velikov

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PhoneGap for Android lets you store local audio files in two places:
 android_asset: file name must start with /android_asset/sound.mp3
 sdcard: file name is just sound.mp3

If you place your DANCE.mp3 file in your project's assets directory, then you can play it using the path:

```
mp3file = new Media("/android_asset/DANCE.mp3",
        function() {
            alert("playAudio():Audio Success");
        },
            function(err) {
                alert(err);
        }
        );
      mp3file.play();
```

(You can read the source for AudioPlayer.java in the Android PhoneGap sources to see how this works.)

Comment: Thank you! This information was difficult for me to find for some reason. Your answer should be marked as the correct answer IMO.

Comment: Sure Jack, I believe you are right. It's been quite some time that I finished that project. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Does this mean that you can not have your media in folders, that it must be in the root to work?

Answer (score 2):

Can I offer an advice..
If you use the PhoneGap Media player.. You need to remove the file:// from the path.. It doesn not accept a full URI for local files
Regards
Kim

Answer (score 1):

I have found out where was my mistake.
The audio file that I want to play was not placed properly, as I thought at first. I had moved it in /sdcard folder and everything was just wonderful!
P.S. I use only filename, no folders.

Comment: how can i access sdcard song and play using javascript?

Comment: Hello @HirenDabhi do you mean playing sound using the PhoneGap API [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_media_media.md.html#Media) or without it?

Comment: How do you save the audio file with phonegap on the sdcard, i thougt phonegap saves all files on the internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just play the songs using the [HTML 5 audio tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp)? Your view is a webView.. is shouldn't matter, it is simpler and you have more control.

Comment: As far as I am aware the <audio> tag is not supported by Android 2.1 & 2.2, isn't it?

Comment: The audio tag is supported in 2.1 and 2.2. But.. it doesn't support any audio formats.

Comment: I would think that plain old html5 doesn't tie into the native audio playing behavior, such as continuing to play when the device goes to sleep.