# using phonegap to play a wav in android

Tags: android, audio, cordova

I am trying to play a wav file from my PG application and it works properly on the iPhone.

I have read all the following:
[audio not working with phoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556437/audio-not-working-with-phonegap)
[How to play song in Android - phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159117/how-to-play-song-in-android-phonegap)
[Playing local sound in phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438822/playing-local-sound-in-phonegap)

I am using PGB to compile my app and its using PG 1.7.0.

I just can figure out how to make it play :(

I tried using

```
function getPhoneGapPath() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.substr( path, path.length - 10 );
    return 'file://' + path;
};

var pathToCheerFile=getPhoneGapPath()+ 'sounds/cheer.wav';
console.log('pathToCheerFile=',pathToCheerFile);

return new Media(pathToCheerFile,
        // success callback
        function() {
            console.log("cheer Audio loaded Success");
        },
        // error callback
        function(err) {
            console.log("cheer Audio load Error: " , err);
        },
);
```

The console is showing `pathToCheerFile=file:///android_asset/www/sounds/cheer.wav`
and later it shows `cheer Audio load Error:` with err being an object that has a single property `code:1`.

any ideas on what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I am also asking for `<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>` in my config.xml although I am not sure this is needed at all... (is it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the "file://" from your path and it should play just fine.

Comment: finally... Thanks...
DO you know if I need the <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/> permission or not ?